# What's the best practice for generating Rails models at runtime based on table structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to use Rails with a database where the schema is outside my control.

One of the points about this database is that a separate process generates table names for particular clients, in the following way:

```
prefix_clientname1
prefix_clientname2
prefix_clientname3
```

All of these tables have the same schema, but with different data.

What's the best way of having models created to access this data?

I'm not necessarily bothered if I cannot access them directly by class: it might be useful to have something like `ModelName.client("foo").find(:all)` or a similar API.

Is this even doable with ActiveRecord or should I look at something like DataMapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with is to define a class that defines the classes through metaprogramming.

```
class Orders
  def self.by_name(identifier)
    class_name = "Orders" + identifier.classify
    if Object.const_defined?(class_name)
      return Object.const_get(class_name)
    else
      new_class = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
        set_table_name 'orders_' + identifier
      end
      Object.const_set(class_name, new_class)
      return new_class
    end
  end
end
```

This lets one access a table by calling `Orders.by_name`:

```
Orders.by_name("foobar").find(:all, :limit => 5)
OrdersFoobar.find(:all, :limit => 5)
```

Obviously, they can be initialized at bootup.